# Authenticating a user without asking for credentials using PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to make something like this:

Basically, I have one site (the main site) where people authenticate and create accounts. Their data is sent to a MySQL database.

On the other side, there’s another site. That site needs the users username (because I’d like to show it) and if they are not logged into their account on the first site, I want the second site to redirect them to the first site where they eventually create and account or login.

I’m also going to give an example where this is used. Let’s take Microsoft, they have their Microsoft accounts and a login page, and other services such as azure and office. They all use Microsoft’s original login without them needing to login each time they open that service, nor even the first time if they are already logged into their Microsoft account.

(I have the main site coded in PHP)

Could you maybe help?

Comment: You find a PHP authentication library that is actively maintained with a history of security fixes (e.g. https://github.com/socialconnect/auth), and then you read up on how to use it? This is not something you ever roll your own code for, unless you're already a security expert, at which point you _really_ know why you should never roll your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I’ve been looking for something like this for a while!

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variable.
In your main site you can save login in a variable like $_SESSION['user_auth_ok']
In every page of both websites you can use:

```
<?php  
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_auth_ok'])) {
    header("Location: main-site/login.php");
}
```

So, everytime a not authenticate user try to access a reserved page will redirect to main site login page.